# change eclipse block comment style

Tags: eclipse

I want to change the block comment, globally, from

```
/*
 *
 *
 */
```

to

```
/*


 */
```

but keep this style:

```
/**
 *
 *
 */
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I think you can't since I cant find an option for that in preference>Java>Code Style>Formatter. By the way this is surely a non recommended way to comment. Why do you want to make this ?

Comment: If I comment out a block of code without the stars, I can easily copy them to other places without much work to remove these stars.

Comment: If your problem is to easily uncomment a block just use `ctrl`+`/`